# sty file not found (maybe related to python update?)

Tags: packages

When running `pdflatex` on ubuntu 18.04 I get `LaTeX Error: File marginnote.sty not found.`

```
locate marginnote.sty
```

gives

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lwarp/lwarp-marginnote.sty
```

But he does find e. g. amssymb.

```
locate amssymb
```

gives

```
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/fonts/amsfonts/amssymb.pdf
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/amssymb.4ht
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/plain/font-change/default-amssymbols.tex
```

Furthermore

```
latex --version
```

gives

```
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.2.3
Copyright 2017 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.34; using libpng 1.6.34
Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11
Compiled with poppler version 0.62.0
```

I now applied `sudo texhash /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist` but that did not help.

The reason probably is that I did some updates with python3 before (up to then everthing worked fine), e. g.

```
sudo apt autoremove python2
sudo apt autoremove python2.7
sudo apt install -y python3-pip
```

Can you help me to get pdflatex running again (this is more important to me than python3 and pip3)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This helped:

> sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-extra

(And as I see during installation this uses python2.7; so indeed removing python2.7 caused the problem.)

Comment: Yep, LaTeX packaging in Ubuntu is a pain. I wish they could provide fake packages and just install a full TeXLive...